# Are there any disadvantages in running a batch file from a web application?

Tags: performance, security, web-applications, batch-file

From within my web application (ASP.NET/C#) I would need to create a button that, once clicked, can run a local batch file (Like in "C:/program files/batch.bch".

This batch runs a shell application that is installed on each client machine of our intranet.

Are there any drawbacks (performance/security/processes) in running the batch file from the web application?

Comment: Are you planning to execute the script from the web-browser or by the web-server (with domain admin permissions and a tool like psexec)?

Comment: The web application is executed on the web server with a service account (with admin rights). Users will access my web app within intranet and the idea would be to provide a button in order to run (if possible) the batch file that each user has on his/her client machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute a client-side script by a central server and execute it with domain admin permissions you will get a security problem as local admins may change the script and therefore will be able to execute anything they want with domain admin permissions.
I would call that and privilege escalation vulnerability.

I would try to only execute programs/commands on the server that directly change data on the client (e.g. access the file-system via share or access the registry remotely).

Additionally as far as I remember the user will not get any GUI feedback therefore it is up to the server to monitor the output and success/failure state.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your hints about security issues. The batch is a shell based application, extension .bch (Multiple Session Batch File - made by IBM). My goal is to let the users being able to run that client application from the web application. The application itself would run separately from the web application. I would like simple to "start" it from there, if possible.